# Mathematics Courses for Computer Scientists

Tags: education, mathematical-analysis

I am looking for standard math courses (Calculus 1, Calculus 2, Linear Algebra, etc.) that were developed specifically for computer scientists, and use computer-science examples for motivation. For example, the pagerank algorithm can be used to motivate eigenvectors and eigenvalues.

Comment: If this doesn't get good answers here, it might do better at [matheducators.se]. It can be moved over there if necessary (or wanted) so please don't cross-post, which is frowned on in most Stack Exchange sites.

Comment: What research have you done?  Have you done a survey of the courses that are offered at major CS universities?  For instance, take a look at 15-251 (Great Ideas in Theoretical Computer Science) at CMU, and CS 70 at UC Berkeley.  Are you familiar with Concrete Mathematics (Graham, Knuth, Patashnik)?

Comment: This question is heading towards a list of items, so I'm closing it. List of items do not work well in the Stack Exchange format. This question could be made to work if you made it more specific — for example, I'd split off calculus and algebra, maybe even more. I also recommend [calling for expertise rather than items](http://cs.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask). You may edit your question here, or (probably better) ask an improved question on [matheducators.se], which seems more appropriate given the topic.

Answer (score 3):

The Matrix in Computer Science (Brown)
http://cs.brown.edu/courses/cs053/current/lectures.htm

Coding the Matrix (Coursera)
https://www.coursera.org/course/matrix

Both are by Philip Klein
http://cs.brown.edu/~pnk/

Comment: We generally prefer answers to be more than just links, but rather to contain some explanation (e.g., what is good about those courses, how they fit the requirements, and why you are recommending them).

Answer (score 1):

David Forsyth in my department (UIUC) developed a course and notes on probability for CS majors. It ties the teaching of probability/stats to applications coming from data analysis. Also has matlab programming etc. See link below.

http://luthuli.cs.uiuc.edu/~daf/courses/Probcourse/Probcourse-2013/498-home.html

Mehran Sahami has a course on probability for CS majors. See info at the link below.

http://www.stanford.edu/class/cs109/index.html