# A road-map for mathematics needed in CS?

Tags: discrete-mathematics

Before asking my question, I have to give some background about myself. I live in Iraq and this made my education a total disaster. My middle/high school math skills are not that great and I never realized that until I got into college. I found out pretty late that great colleges cover a lot of maths materials in their curriculum. And now I'm a junior majoring in CS and still I don't feel really confident about my skills. I wish to continue studying CS and maybe acquire a masters degree. I searched about the maths needed for an undergraduate, and it seems that I need to focus on three important subjects:

- Calculus
- Discrete Maths
- Linear Algebra

Do you have any books recommendation or a road map to follow to achieve a good level of understating for the subjects mentioned above?

P.S: I don't care how long or complicated the materials or books are, I have all the time in the world and I can dedicate 5 hours daily(10 in the summer).

Comment: You question is opinion-based. Nevertheless, the more and more advanced mathematics you know the better. However, first you should master the necessary knowledge which I believe is provided by the university where you are studying. In any case you can Google, or visit any university and look at their curriculum. For example, [MIT OCW](https://ocw.mit.edu/courses/electrical-engineering-and-computer-science/) is a good starting point. Also you can have a look at [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14868480/math-for-computer-science).

Comment: [Another post](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/26210/mathematics-courses-for-computer-scientists).

Comment: @fade2black I'm sorry I wasn't clear enough, but almost all of my instructors don't really know what they are talking about. And the curriculum is garbage. What we cover in 3 years is covered by Harvard in 1 semester.

Comment: In my opinion: Calculus, Discrete Math, Probability and Stat, Linear Algebra, Diff Equations are the most essential. Once you feel confident at these subjects, then depending on what you would like to study you could choose more advanced themes. *Discrete Math and Its Applications* by K.H. Rosen is a good textbook.

Comment: @fade2black It depends very much on what you want to do. Having worked in logic, algorithms and complexity theory, I've not solved a differential equation since first-year undergrad.

Comment: @DavidRicherby I'm want to learn all the maths that I can and I'm not really concerned about any specific field, since maths will be helpful no matter what.